# Regex - Match a URL but not the proceeding line numbers in a Stack Trace

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am writing a ASP.Net application that will poll a log database used for other applications and display the logs in an easy readable way. I've got the basic functionality working but I would like to "linkify" the URLs that appear in the StackTrace so that clicking on them will open up the relevant file.

```
at initialiseProducts (http://localhost:51940/POS/POS.js:520:22)
    at Object.success (http://localhost:51940/POS/POS.js:67:17)
    at i (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:28017)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:28783)
    at A (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:14017)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:16305)
```

After some trawling of StackOverflow I found a Regex that will detect my URLs without issue

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
```

However it will also match the line and column numbers `:520:22` at the end of the URLs, which means that when the links are clicked the file cannot be found.

Is it possible to modify this Regex to ignore the line and column numbers at the end of each URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your regex, you can exclude the line and column numbers from capture like this:

```
 (\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*):\d+:\d+
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Xi4WtX/2)

The group 1 contains your urls.

```js
const regex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*?):\d+:\d+/ig;
const str = `at initialiseProducts (http://localhost:51940/POS/POS.js:520:22)
    at Object.success (http://localhost:51940/POS/POS.js:67:17)
    at i (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:28017)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:28783)
    at A (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:14017)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (http://localhost:51940/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:16305)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Atomic Grouping doesn't seem to be available in Javascript sadly, is there a way around it?

Comment: check the updated answer, my bad didn't see you've tagged js @ConorWatson

Comment: Fantastic that seems to work well! I've added extra brackets to make the line/column numbers into their own group `(:\d+:\d+)`